# Apex regex to get html child tag and its content?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I have below HTML tag and i need to extract  TAG child tag and its element.

```
<h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">
<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
<span>get the content</span>
</a>

</h3>
```

I want to extract following string from the code.

```
 <a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
    <span>get the content</span>
    </a>
```

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
<h3[^<>]*class="large lheight20 margintop10"[^<>]*>(?<content>.*?)</h3>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Salesforce?

Comment: @adrian larson this have to do with salesforce. i am getting response from http request in HTML string from apex class and i have to extract text from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the [following pattern](http://rubular.com/r/NIrLViWn63):

```
(?si)<h3[^>]+?>(.*)<\/h3>
```

Explanation:

- `(?si)`

  - The `s` flag indicates that `.` should match newline characters.
  - Might as well use the `i` flag to make it case insensitive.
- `<h3[^>]+?>`

  - Match the opening tag.
- `(.*)`

  - Match all characters as match group 1.
- `<\/h3>`

  - Match the closing tag.

---

Here is the script I used in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
String markup = '<h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">\n' +
    '<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">\n' +
    '<span>get the content</span>\n' +
    '</a>\n\n</h3>';
Matcher regex = Pattern.compile('(?si)<h3[^>]+?>(.*)<\\/h3>').matcher(markup);
system.debug(regex.find());
system.debug(regex.group(1));
```

Comment: Note that this will match multiple elements as one, e.g. `<h3><a>...</a></h3><h3><b>...</b></h3>` will be a single match with the group `<a>...</a></h3><h3><b>...</b>` due to the greedyness of `(.*)`. If you want to avoid that, you *can* use a `?` after `*`, i.e. `(.*?)`, to enforce lazy matching, *but* you're probably better off with a solution that uses a parser like the one in the answer from Derek F.

Comment: Yes parsing is better. I Should change to *? though. Will investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions work on regular languages, but [HTML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). So, while you can do some limited extraction of html using a regexp, regexps are not the right tool for the job.

Instead, I'd suggest using the [Dom.Document class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) and the [Dom.XmlNode class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm%23apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode)

A brief example to get you going

```
Dom.Document inDoc = new Dom.Document();
inDoc.load(htmlStringInput);

Dom.XmlNode root = inDoc.getRootElement();

Dom.XmlNode aTag = root.getChildElement('a', null);
Dom.XmlNode spanTag = aTag.getChildElement('span', null);

System.debug('extracted hyperlink: ' + aTag.getAttributeValue('href', null));
System.debug('extracted link text: ' + spanTag.getText());
```

I'm not exactly sure how you'd go about getting the string representation of the link tag (from the Dom.XmlNode) once you extracted it from the root, and I don't have the ability to play around with it today. I'll try to keep this in mind and see if I can work something out tomorrow if you truly need the entire content (attributes and children) of the link tag instead of the href and span text.

Comment: Thank you so much  I am getting error System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: TEXT seen ...ight="1" src="https://tracking.-st.com/h/v2/ns-sa?nw=1&amp;siteUrl=... @70:84)" there are some unsupported character for XML.  how to remove all.

Comment: That error message doesn't seem complete (missing the illegal character, assuming the character is printable). If you're getting this from an `httpResponse`, are you passing the result of `getBodyDocument()` into the `load()` method of the `Dom.Document()`? I don't see any obvious invalid character sequences, so I don't have any ideas beyond that. This might be the start of another question.